# Fill combobox with multiple datasets from the same database column at the same time

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, checkbox, combobox

I have a combobox that is filled from a database conditionally by checking off one of 10 checkboxes. Each of the 10 checkboxes contains the code below, which selects a portion of `column` based on a value in `column2`.

```
private void Check1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (Check1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            // SQL Server connection
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server = Server; Database = DB; Integrated Security = True");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Column1] FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE [Column2] = 50", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);
                combo1.DisplayMember = "Column1";
                combo1.ValueMember = "ID";
                combo1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception Message
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }

        if (Check1.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            combo1.DataSource = null;
        }
```

Therefore, it is rather trivial to fill the combobox with each separate condition. What I want to do that I'm not sure of the approach, however, is that when more than one checkbox is checked, the combobox will display the data from every checked checkbox at once (all this data will be from the same column). Moreover, when a single checkbox is then unchecked, I only want it to remove its own dataset from the combobox and not everything.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does your checkboxes value have the value you want to search for in the DB?  If so loop through checkbox list and get the values that are checked.  Then build your SQL using an IN statement that contain all the values for the checkboxes that are checked.

Comment: How do I give a checkbox a value?

Comment: By populating the Value property of the item. Also, I would encourage you to change a couple things here. You have an anti-pattern that I call try/squelch. You are not handling errors, you are burying them. It seems like you are doing that so you can have a finally to close and dispose of your connection. You should instead wrap both the connection AND the command objects in a USING. Then you don't have to use this technique or code the dispose method.

Comment: I actually tried to put it in a using block, but it kept giving me an error that I couldn't figure out, so I just did it without it. Would it possible for you to show me an example of what you mean by looping through the checkbox list?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible if you have 1 dataset and then you dynamically build up your SQL query. Set up a variable for the columns you want to return based on all the selected comboBoxes.

Use 1 method for all your after update event on the comboBoxes to make it easier and more maintainable.

In terms of mapping the dynamics columns to the dropdowns, I don't work with Winform so I'm not sure but hope this can help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for `loop` to iterate the values you have retrieved and append the combo box value. Example:

```
 comboBox.Items.Clear(); // <-- Declare this at initialization of the page or whatever scenario you have

    private void Check1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (Check1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                // SQL Server connection
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server = Server; Database = DB; Integrated Security = True");
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Column1] FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE [Column2] = 50", conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(ds);

// Using loop to iterate the values and append the combo box
                    for(int i=0;i<da.Rows.Count;i++)
                   {
                         combo1.Items.Add(da[i]["Column1"].ToString());
                        combo1.Items[combo1.Itemx.Count-1].Text=da[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                        combo1.Items[combo1.Itemx.Count-1].Value=da[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                   }



                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Exception Message
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
            }

            if (Check1.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                combo1.DataSource = null;
            }
```

This is just an example, hope you can get the idea